# how to deselect one image when user selects other image in android studio

Tags: android

Here is the code of selection

```html
 holder.tvTreatmentArea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectedAreasList[position] = !selectedAreasList[position];

                if (selectedAreasList[position]) {
                    holder.layoutTreatmentAreas.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_circular_selected));
                    holder.tvTreatmentArea.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                    holder.imgTreatmentSelectedStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_24_px);
                    if (mCallbacks != null) {
                        mCallbacks.onButtonClicked(treatmentAreasList.get(position).getPrice(), "Added", treatmentAreasList.get(position).getArea());
                    }
                } else {
                    holder.layoutTreatmentAreas.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_circular));
                    holder.tvTreatmentArea.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.treatment_clinic_header));
                    holder.imgTreatmentSelectedStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.oval);
                    if (mCallbacks != null) {
                        mCallbacks.onButtonClicked(treatmentAreasList.get(position).getPrice(), "Removed", treatmentAreasList.get(position).getArea());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

How to deselect previously selected image when user selects other image in android studio. I am using recycler view in which I inflated images and one image get selected I want to deselect the other image. is it possible to save reference of previously selected image in recycler view?

Comment: you may store the position of selected image then call notifyDataSetChanged(); , post the code of image selection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to save previous reference just save your current selected position when someone clicks on particular image via `getAdapterPosition()` and after that you just need to use `notifiydatastchanged` to update the list with newly selected image.

In `bindview` you need to write logic for that.

Rough Example:

```
YourAdapter{
  int selectedPosition = -1;


  onBindView(...,..,int postion){
     if(postion==selectedPosition){
        update the background or button for this position
     }

    onClick(){
     selectedPosition = getAdapterPosition();
     notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your answer with example

Comment: You can use imgv.setTag() and imagv.getTab() method to get which one is click